# The Torah warns us twelve times about observing the Shabbos

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat

Rabbi Abraham Danzig writes:

> והזהירה התורה על שמירת השבת י"ב פעמים, The Torah warns us twelve times
>   about observing the Shabbos.

([*Chayei Adam*, *Shabbat and Festivals*](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam%2C_Shabbat_and_Festivals.1.1?vhe=Chayei_Adam,_Vilna,_1844&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) 1:1)

Does anyone happen to know where those twelve places are?

Comment: I count:

1. Gen 2,
2. Exo 16,
3. Exo 20,
4. Exo 23,
5. Exo 31,
6. Exo 34,
7. Exo 35,
8. Lev 19,
9. Lev 23,
10. Lev 26,
11. Num 15,
12. Deu 5

But he may have had a different count.

Comment: I vagualy remember it being mentioned in Perek Reb Elizer dmilah

Comment: @DoubleAA Why do you count Gen. 2 as a “warning” on Shabbos? It’s about Shabbos, sure, but there’s no אזהרה in it.

Comment: @Doniel so too num 15. I don't know how he counted

Comment: By the way, the count of 12 isn't original to the Chayei Adam; it's found in Rambam's Sefer Hamitzvos, Shoresh 9. Possibly one of the commentaries there might list them, though so far I haven't found any.

Comment: Sry ,I confused it with milah ,which the gemara says has 13 brisos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Meir, I found that the **Rambam** in **Sefer HaMitzvos** [*Shoresh* § 9](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Shorashim.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) brings this concept. In the Shabsi Frankel edition they list the following twelve places:

1. [Exodus 20:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
2. [Exodus 23:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.23.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
3. [Exodus 31:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
4. [Exodus 31:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
5. [Exodus 31:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
6. [Exodus 31:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
7. [Exodus 34:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
8. [Exodus 35:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.35.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
9. [Leviticus 19:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
10. [Leviticus 23:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
11. [Leviticus 26:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.26.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
12. [Deuteronomy 5:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.5.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

After checking out the [**Rav Kapach**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Qafih) edition of **Sefer HaMitzvos**, I found he has the exact same list. I assume Shabsi Frankel got it from him. **Rav Kapach** doesn't provide a source for his list, nor does he cross reference an earlier source for the **Rambam**'s count. I assume then that the **Rambam** is the originator of this counting.